# Java - how to convert an object in to a variable?

Tags: java, string, object, int

I'm working on a programming lanuage, i need to convert an object (like var in javascript) in to the type of variable it should be. Ex:

```
if(object == variabletypes.string)
{
//convert object to string
}
else if(object ==variabletypes.int)
{
//convert to integer
}
```

Thanks for your time, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Is it not already the type it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you've got a `java.lang.Object`, this is a start:

```
Object o = /* ??? */;
if (o instanceof String)
{
    String s = (String) o;
}
else if (o instanceof Integer)
{
    Integer integer = (Integer) o;
    int i = integer.intValue();
}
```

The "conversion" here is primarily [casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), operating under the assumption that the object already has the correct runtime type, and that you don't need to actually alter the internal representation — for instance, by changing a `String` to an `int` with [`Integer#parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Other potentially useful methods (since the question isn't exactly clear) may include:

- [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29)
- [`Class#cast(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(yourObject instanceof String){
    String str = (String)yourObject;
}
else if (yourObject instanceof Integer){
    Integer yourInt = (Integer)yourObject;
}
else if{
     System.out.println("My object is a class of: "+ yourObject.getClass().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
object.toString(); // Returns the string value of the object, if it exists.
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of tools available in Java:

1. The `instanceof` operator
2. The `getClass().getName()` calls, which will give you the name of the object's actual class as a String.

I don't know what you mean by "convert", but these are the basic tools you have available.

Comment: Now that I understand this, i meant 'cast'